# Hibernate Criteria Query Issue with Projection and restriction

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to get selected columns from a table using hibernate criteria query

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(OfferCashbackMaster.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.property("txnType"), "txnType")
      .add(Projections.property("off_Discription"), "off_Discription"))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(OfferCashbackMaster.class))
    .add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("aggregatorId", aggregatorId),
                           Restrictions.eq("txnType", txnType)));
```

The name `txnType` mentioned in projection is having a clash with restriction.

Giving me the following error

```
Hibernate: 
select 
    this_.OFFER_CODE as y0_, 
    this_.TXN_TYPE as y1_, 
    this_.VALID_TO as y2_, 
    this_.OFFER_DISCRIPTION as y3_ 
    from OFFER_CASHBACK_MASTER this_ 
where 
    (this_.AGGREGATOR_ID=? and y1_=?)

2018-02-25/15:42:41.756  WARN: util.JDBCExceptionReporter - 
SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2018-02-25/15:42:41.757 ERROR: util.JDBCExceptionReporter - 
Unknown column 'y1_' in 'where clause'
```

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Please add your OfferCashbackMaster class and its xml mapping if applicable. Also add your hibernate config  xml / java class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using  Hibernate `3.2.6, 3.0.5, 3.5.5, 3.6.0.Beta3` then it's time for migrating to newer version of Hibernate.

Reported bug: **Criteria Query Issue with Projection and restriction**

Link: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3371

Affects Version/s: `3.2.6 3.0.5, 3.5.5, 3.6.0.Beta3`

Component/s: query-criteria

Fix Version: 3.6.0.Beta4 and above.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're using the outdated version of hibernate.

The issue is addressed and resolved for a long time:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-817

Fixed version: `3.6.0.Beta4`